# What is the best way to loop in a circular way over a container (vector)?

Tags: c++, boost

I need to loop in a circular way over a container, such that for every iteration, I have access to a current and the previous element. For the first iteration, the previous element should be the `back` element of a container.

This example is doing that:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    vector<int> v = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6}; 

    auto xPreviousIt = v.end(); 
    --xPreviousIt; 

    int i = 0; 
    for (auto xCurrent : v)
    {
        cout << xCurrent <<  "  " << *xPreviousIt << endl; 
        xPreviousIt = v.begin() + i;  
        ++i; 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

but I want to know if there is a better way of achieving something like this? Like a circular iterator that starts at the begining of a container and ends there as well? All I could find in boost was the [circular buffer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/circular_buffer.html).

Comment: writing an iterator which wraps the original iterator pair and does that with a bit of overhead is certainly doable.

Comment: It sounds like the Boost::circular_buffer is what you want.  What about it does not meet your goals?

Comment: @ZacHowland: first thing that comes to mind is that I don't have fixed, but variable storage. The number of elements stored in the container varies when specific algorithms are applied.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: I'll try this, maybe: I don't know how many algorithms will require circulation yet.

Comment: @tomislav-maric `boost::circular_buffer` is fixed at runtime, not compile time.  If you want a larger buffer for different algorithms, you simply create one with the larger size by passing a larger parameter into the constructor.  Since `std::vector` (potentially) would have to reallocate when you add items, it is not really different if you have to reconstruct the buffer and copy the elements when you want a larger size.

Comment: @ZacHowland: std::vector is optimized for reallocation (depending on the implementation), so expanding and shrinking may be more efficient than re-allocating every time. the problem is that I don't know the size of the algorithm result beforehand, which in turn results with N reallocations for the circular buffer where N is the size of the result, and vector expands with a strategy that optimizes memory use. still, I will check this out and do a benchmark, maybe it works out. thank you!

Comment: @tomislav-maric If I understand you correctly, you expect a given algorithm A to provide you with N results and an algorithm B to provide you with M results.  If that is the case, what do you need the circular buffer for at all?  Just use a vector as the container for the algorithm, and if you want to keep the results in a circular_buffer afterwards, just copy the results from the output vector into a circular_buffer of the desired size after the algorithm.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

It is simpler to use an ordinary for loop. If for example init is a starting index then you could write

```
for ( std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < v.size(); i++ )
{
   std::cout << v[( init + i ) % v.size()] << ' ';
}

std::cout << std::endl;
```

Comment: I agree, it's simpler for a single usage. but if you do this often, you probably want to decouple the iteration from the actual work. this has the added benefit, that you can use *algorithms*.